# Error Message:lookupTransform base_link to laser timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i run roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch and rplidar_ros rplidar.launch , i get an error message lookupTransform base_link to laser timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame.

I am able to open up RVIZ, but displays Fixed Frame: No tf data. Actual error: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist.

My tf tree says no tf data received.

Here is all my rostopic list:
/clicked_point
/initialpose
/map
/map_metadata
/map_updates
/move_base_simple/goal
/poseupdate
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/scan
/slam_cloud
/slam_out_pose
/syscommand
/tf
/tf_static
/trajectory

Here is my launch file:

```
<!-- Frame names -->
<param name="map_frame" value="map" />
<param name="base_frame" value="base_link" />
<param name="odom_frame" value="base_link" />

<!-- Tf use -->
<param name="use_tf_scan_transformation" value="true"/>
<param name="use_tf_pose_start_estimate" value="false"/>
<param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="false"/>

<!-- Map size / start point -->
<param name="map_resolution" value="0.050"/>
<param name="map_size" value="$(arg map_size)"/>
<param name="map_start_x" value="0.5"/>
<param name="map_start_y" value="0.5" />
<param name="map_multi_res_levels" value="2" />
```

-->
 -->

```
<!-- Map update parameters -->
<param name="update_factor_free" value="0.4"/>
<param name="update_factor_occupied" value="0.9" />    
<param name="map_update_distance_thresh" value="0.4"/>
<param name="map_update_angle_thresh" value="0.06" />
<param name="laser_z_min_value" value = "-1.0" />
<param name="laser_z_max_value" value = "1.0" />

<!-- Advertising config --> 
<param name="advertise_map_service" value="true"/>

<param name="scan_subscriber_queue_size" value="$(arg scan_subscriber_queue_size)"/>
<param name="scan_topic" value="$(arg scan_topic)"/>

<!-- Debug parameters -->

  <param name="output_timing" value="false"/>
  <param name="pub_drawings" value="true"/>
  <param name="pub_debug_output" value="true"/>
  </node>
```

-->

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256924/error-message:lookuptransform-base_link-to-laser-timed-out.-could-not-transform-laser-scan-into-base_frame./) by [Shilpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29620/shilpan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2017-03-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shilpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29620/shilpan/) on 2017-03-14**:
if i add Laser Scan to RVIZ ans select topic as scan, then i get error message: Transform [sender=unknown_publisher]
For frame [laser]: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-14**:
Please change the title of your question (use the *edit* button next to the title). Make it short and to the point, so it describes your actual issue. Do not include "plz help" and try to refrain from copy-pasting actual error messages into it.

**Comment by [Shilpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29620/shilpan/) on 2017-03-14**:
Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Issue resolved with tf code messages in hector_slam launch files.

---

Originally posted by [Shilpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29620/shilpan/) with karma: 96 on 2017-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosfun](https://answers.ros.org/users/29313/rosfun/) on 2017-03-28**:
what changes did you make and in which files?